# Fullcalendar 5 with Angular: Component inside Event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fullcalendar, angular12

Recently, my company switched from AngularJS to Angular 12. Now I am using Fullcalendar version 5 instead of version 3. I am using the Angular implementation of Fullcalendar:https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular

Obviously, many things don't work anymore. See the following image to get an understanding of what I want to achieve:[image]
As you can see, there is custom HTML inside the event. It is not hard to render custom HTML there, but there is a button in the top right corner of every event that copies the event. When I was using angularJS, this worked fine as I was able to call functions in the angularJS controller. This does not work anymore.

I struggle to find a proper solution for triggering a function inside the angular context, but failed to find anything useful on the internet. The main issue is that I can write all the custom HTML that I want, but the content is not compiled by angular (or rather, outside of angular scope), therefore a simple `(click)="copyEvent(event)"` wont work. I know I could do some hacky approach by using `onclick="hackyFunction(eventId)"` to trigger the click, but I'd rather use a real angular component inside the event. Do you have any suggestions on how to approach this issue?

Comment: (click)="copyEvent($event)" ... does using the $ help?

Comment: i meant event as in *ngFor="let event of events", not using, any parameters also does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was not able to find any proper way of injecting a component into the event, so I came up with this hacky solution:
[image]
As you can see, Im using the EventRenderHook to render my custom HTML. To make it possible to access the Angular context, i used "`window.autoswitch.functionName`". Autoswitch in this case is just a variable I generated on the window as a reference to the component: `(window as any).autoswitch = this;` "this" is the component. I wrote this statement in "`ngOnInit()`"

The functions were added simply like that:
[image]